# How to do case insensitive match with regexmatch in google sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to filter my sheet with

```
=filter({B:B}, regexmatch({B:B}, $A$1))
```

Is it possible to make regexmatch case insensitive?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not sure exactly what is `$A$1`, but the second parameter is still a regular expression, so I am assuming you can pass [a flag/modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) like:

`=filter({B:B}, regexmatch({B:B}, "(?i)in"))`

if `$A$1` is a string, maybe you can use the `concatenate` function so the output result is the flag plus your value:

`=filter({B:B}, regexmatch({B:B}, CONCATENATE("(?i)", $A$1)))`

Comment: I just use & to cat the strings together but maybe I'm doing it wrong: `=filter({B:B}, regexmatch({B:B}, "(?i)" & $A$1))`

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
=regexmatch($I1,"(?i)tex")
```

Answer (score 3):

The braces are not required:

```
=filter(B:B,regexmatch(B:B,$A$1))
```

should work for case insensitive just as for case sensitive, *provided* that for the former the A1 cell is prepended: `(?i)`. That is, if the term is `tex`, in A1:

```
(?i)tex
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```txt
 =filter(B:B, lower(regexmatch(B:B)), lower($A$1))
```

The LOWER function internally supresses all capitals, rendering both the searched data and the search term case equivalent, and without modifying the actual data onscreen.

Answer (score 0):

=filter({B:B}, regexmatch(upper(B:B), upper($A$1)))